# Show Enum values according to Display attribute in DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, enums

I have this class `State`:

```
public enum State
    {
        Ok,
        [Display(Name = "Not Submitted")]     
        NotSubmited,
        [Display(Name = "Repeat Request")]
        RepeatRequest,
        Sent,
        Error,
        Response
    }
```

How can I display in a `DropDownList` the `enum` values making use of the `Display` attributes, considering that the `Display` attributes are user friendly?
I've been trying but I always get the raw values(`NotSubmitted, RepeatRequest` without space..)

This is my code for the `DropDownList`:

```
   <select name="Response[@index].State" class="form-control">
        <option value="">Select State</option>
        @foreach (var state in Enum.GetValues(typeof(State)))     
            {
                <option>@state</option>
            }
    </select>
```

And:

```
var ValuesArray =Enum.GetValues(typeof(Status));
var NamesArray = Enum.GetNames(typeof(Status));
```

But still getting always the not friendly values...(`NotSubmitted` instead of `Not Submitted` for example)

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="Response[@index].State" class="form-control">
    <option value="">Select State</option>
    @foreach (var state in Enum.GetValues(typeof(State)))     
        {
            <option>Enum.GetName(typeof(State), state )</option>
        }
</select>
```

Comment: it's not working in my project.. I'm having the same results..`NotSubmitted`, `RepeatRequest`...